# TYPO3 Database import

Tags: database, visual-studio-code, import, typo3, code-composer

How can I import a database at my TYPO3 Backend? I use Visual Studio Code with composer as a SSH for the server where I write the code for backend. I also have an extension "external import" but im not sure if I can import a database with this extension.

I have a sample database which I want to try to import. I already tried with the following command which I entered at the terminal of Visual Studio Code:

`mysql -h 127.0.0.3 -u db12345_678 -p db12345_678 < dateiname.sql`

It requires a password which I don't know what password it can be. I'm not even sure if this command will work and will show the imported database at TYPO3 frontend then.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the database password of your TYPO3 installation you can try to look it up in `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php` or `typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php`.

Please note that `AdditionalConfiguration.php` (if present) always takes precedence over `LocalConfiguration.php`.

Regardless of the database credentials maybe your hosting provider has a PhpMyadmin installation. Otherwise there are TYPO3 extensions like phpmyadmin or t3adminer in the TYPO3 Extension Repository but be very careful when using these extensions in production!